# Finite dimensional associative division algebras over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I know the following two facts of division algebras:

- The finite dimensional associative division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$.
- The finite dimensional associative division algebras over $\mathbb{F}_q$ are just the finite field extensions.

So I was wondering, what do we know about finite dimensional field extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$? Or more precisely: *Can they all be embedded into $\mathbb{H}$?*

I know that division algebras in the form of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ are just number fields. Is it possible to do something with that fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are division algebras with centre $\Bbb Q$ of dimension $n^2$
for any positive integer $n$. For $n\ge3$ they do not embed in $\Bbb H$.
These division algebras can be constructed as [cyclic algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_system#Cyclic_algebra).

Comment: How do we know about the lack of embedding?

Comment: If a division algebra $D$ over $\Bbb Q$ embeds in an $\Bbb R$-algebra, so does $D\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb R$ (as it is simple).

Comment: Awesome! I will definitely look further into this subject.

Comment: @Mar There's a lot on this in Pierce's *Associative Algebras* in Springer's GTM series.

Answer (score 3):

A finite-dimensional field extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic. Moreover, since char$(\mathbb{Q})=0$, the extension is separable, so by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) there exists some $\alpha\in F$ such that $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

As for the second question: See $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and see $\mathbb{C}$ as the subring $\mathbb{R}[1,i]\subseteq\mathbb{H}$. Then you have an injective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ to $\mathbb{H}$.

**ADDED: The noncommutative case**

The noncommutative case is harder, with proofs based in ramification of ideals and $p$-adic fields (proofs were recopiled by Albert in his **Structure of Algebras** of 1939, Chapter IX).

If $D$ is a noncommutative algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $D$ is a cyclic algebra over its center $Z(D)$, i.e., there are a finite-dimensional field extension $F/Z(D)$ of dimension $n$ with cyclic Galois group generated by $\sigma$, and a nonzero element $\alpha\in Z(D)$ such that for every $x\in D$ we have $x=x_0+x_1y+\ldots+x_{n-1}y^{n-1}$, with $x_i\in F$, $y\in D$ such that $y^n=\alpha$ and noncommutative multiplication given by $yz:=\sigma(z)y$ for every $z\in D$.

Comment: How about non-commutative division algebras? Do they necessarily embed in $\mathbb{H}$? It was not asked explicitly in the question, but from the formulation I suppose it is also relevant.

Comment: The title suggests that non-commutative cases were desired.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something that should be fixed?