# Division Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We know that if $A$ is a division algebra, then $\dim(A) \in \{1,2,4,8 \}$, with the basic examples are: $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}, \mathbb{O}$.

My question: Is there some another different example of division algebra (that are not isomorphisms to the cited examples)?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to division algebras over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: A division algebra $A$ is a algebra with the propertie: $a.b = 0 \implies a = 0 \vee b = 0, \text{ } \forall a, \text{ } b \in A$.

And a algebra $A$ is a vector space (over a field) with a bilinear map $m: A \times A \to A$ ($m \left( a,b \right) = a.b$).

Comment: any field is a division algebra so not sure what you ask; eg $\mathbb C(t)$ the field of rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb C$ is a division algebra etc

Comment: Sorry. I see my mistake know: if a algebra $A$ is a REAL division algebra, so $\dim(A) \in \dots$. So, reformulating my question: there is any different examples of division algebras? That are not $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ or $\mathbb{O}$?

Comment: REAL algebra like a algebra $A$ over real numbers. This notation is not good because a *-algebra is real when $a^{*} = a, \text{ } \forall a \in A$.

Comment: @GabrielFanini You already accepted an answer, but yes there are infinitely many (f.d. in fact) over $\mathbb Q$.  E.g., compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2635344/11323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite-dimensional *associative* real division algebras are classified by *[Frobenius' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29)*. Without the finiteness assumption there are of course many more (like $\mathbb{R}(T)$).